# Dynamically exclude some numbers from randomly generated sequence

Tags: c, arduino, sequence

I want to produce a random sequence of numbers between a range, for example `100 to 200`.

After a while, depending on some events, I want to produce a new sequence between the same range (100 to 200), but this time I want to exclude some numbers. For example I don't want `[150,165,170]`.

And the next time, these excluded numbers may or may not be included in the sequence.

One possible approach could be an array of numbers like this:

```
int rndm[] {100,101,102,103,...};
```

and use the index of the array to generate a random number at a time:

```
random(rndm[0-99]);
```

But I need to use as few instruction/data structures as possible in order to achieve performance.

I am using C for this code and I use `random()` or `randomSeed(seed)` and I want to know what the most efficient approach to handle this issue is, in terms of data structures should be used for the speed and memory.

Comment: Your approach looks ok. Anything else would need much more information about your constraints, platform, and in particular your programming language. C and C++ are two different languages, and a random specialization to C++11 does certainly not help either.

Comment: Since it is an experiment, I can use either C or C++. and the platform could be any type of hardware. I want to know the way I can exclude some numbers on any run.

Comment: do you want the new sequence of numbers to be the same as the old sequence, except that certain numbers are to be skipped?

Comment: No, I want a new sequence each time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This solution is efficient in the case that there are not many exclusions during the lifetime, once the exclusion function is quadratic.*

There is a struct called *RandomArray* that holds a pointer to and array with size N. N is the desired size of the sequence. The time and space complexity is linear O(N) for the create function.

When an event happens it shall call the function *excludeValue*, with a time complexity of O(N) and space complexity of 1.

If it is desired to exclude a bunch of values, the function *excludeValues* (pay attention to s at the end) shall be called. In this case the complexity is O(N x K) and the space complexity is 1. K is the amount of values that shall be excluded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct RandomArray {
  int *pData;
  size_t dataLen;
  int excludedIdx;
};
struct RandomArray *excludeValue(struct RandomArray *pAr, int val) {
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < pAr->excludedIdx; ++i) {
    if (pAr->pData[i] == val) {
      pAr->excludedIdx--;
      int tmp = pAr->pData[i];
      pAr->pData[i] = pAr->pData[pAr->excludedIdx];
      pAr->pData[pAr->excludedIdx] = tmp;
      // Do test again the position
      --i;
    }
  }  return pAr;
}

struct RandomArray *excludeValues(struct RandomArray *pAr, int *pVals, size_t len) {
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    excludeValue(pAr, pVals[i]);
}

struct RandomArray *destroyRandomArray(struct RandomArray *pAr) {
  if (pAr) {
    if (pAr->pData)
      free(pAr->pData);
    pAr->dataLen = 0;
  }
  return pAr;
}

struct RandomArray *createRandomArray(
struct RandomArray *pAr,
size_t dataLen,
int lowLimit, int highLimit) {
  int i;
  int range = (highLimit - lowLimit);
  pAr->pData = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * dataLen);
  pAr->dataLen = dataLen;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for (i = 0; i < dataLen; ++i) {
    pAr->pData[i] = rand() % (range + 1) + lowLimit;
  }
  // Clear excluded indexs
  pAr->excludedIdx = pAr->dataLen;  return pAr;
}

void printRandomArray(struct RandomArray *pAr) {
  size_t i;
  printf("Random Array (len = %d): ", pAr->dataLen);
  for (i =0; i < pAr->dataLen; ++i) {
    printf(" %d", pAr->pData[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void printValidRandomArray(struct RandomArray *pAr) {
  size_t i;
  printf("Valid Random Array (len = %d): ", pAr->excludedIdx);
  for (i =0; i < pAr->excludedIdx; ++i) {
    printf(" %d", pAr->pData[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void printExcludedRandomArray(struct RandomArray *pAr) {
  size_t i;
  printf("Excluded Random Array (len = %d): ", pAr->dataLen - pAr->excludedIdx);
  for (i = pAr->excludedIdx; i < pAr->dataLen; ++i) {
    printf(" %d", pAr->pData[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void printAllRandomArray(struct RandomArray *pAr) {
  printRandomArray(pAr);
  printValidRandomArray(pAr);
  printExcludedRandomArray(pAr);
}

int main() {
  int lowLimit = 100;
  int highLimit = 105;
  int arrayLen = 10;
  struct RandomArray myAr;
  createRandomArray(&myAr, arrayLen, lowLimit, highLimit);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  excludeValue(&myAr, 100);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  excludeValue(&myAr, 101);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  excludeValue(&myAr, 102);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  excludeValue(&myAr, 103);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  excludeValue(&myAr, 104);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  excludeValue(&myAr, 105);
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  destroyRandomArray(&myAr);
  createRandomArray(&myAr, arrayLen, lowLimit, highLimit);
  printf("\n\n\n");
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  printf("\n");
  int vals[] = { 102, 105, 104  };
  excludeValues(&myAr, vals, sizeof(vals) / sizeof(vals[0]));
  printAllRandomArray(&myAr);
  destroyRandomArray(&myAr);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This was asked [here on the Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=504473.0) but I saw it here too. My answer is in Arduino's flavor of C++ since it was posted there...

Of course, performance varies as the set of excluded numbers grows relative to the set of numbers to be used to create your "new sequence."

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  randomSeed(analogRead(A0));
}
void loop() {
  // create an arbitray sized array to be filled with unique values to exclude from desired array
  const int arraySize = 5;
  int exclusions[arraySize];  
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    // fill the array with unique values...
    int val;
    do {
      val = random(100, 200);
    } while([&]() {
      for (auto j : exclusions) {
        if (val == j) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }());
    exclusions[i] = val;
  }
  Serial.print(F("Exclusion Array: "));
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    Serial.print(exclusions[i]);
    if (i < arraySize - 1)
    Serial.print(F(", "));
  }
  Serial.println();
  // create a new array of arbitrary length of unique random numbers in >>>the same<<< range as above (but not necessary)
  Serial.print(F("Starting...\n"));
  uint32_t start = millis();
  const int listSize = 32;
  int list[listSize];
  for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    // fill the array with unique values that will exclude exclusions[]
    int val;
    do {
      val = random(100, 200);
    } while([&]() {
      for (auto j : list) {
        if (val == j) {
          return true;
        }
        for (auto k : exclusions) {
          if (val == k) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }());
    list[i] = val;
  }
  uint32_t end = millis();
  Serial.println(end - start);
  // OPTIONAL -> lets sort the final arry to make spotting the duplicates easier:
  for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < listSize; j++) {
      if (list[j] < list[i]) {
        int temp = list[i];
        list[i] = list[j];
        list[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  // output the final array
  Serial.print(F("Final Array: "));
  for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(list[i]);
    if (i < listSize - 1)
    Serial.print(F(", "));
  }
  Serial.print(F("\n\n\n"));
  delay(1000);
}
```